# .Net Wrapper and Memory Space To Solve Global Variable issues

Tags: .net, memory-management, dll

I have an existing C++ DLL that is invoked via LoadLibray from a calling application. It is handed a window, and is expected to operate in that window. In a single window environment (i.e. the DLL is unloaded for the next user and or window), everything is fine. However, I find that when we are handed multiple windows, trouble happens.

I believe the problems are due to the fact that we are sloppy and have quite a bit of global data (i.e. `extern`, or `declare`s outside of a class) and of course, when the window is switched, not all of the data is updated correctly and it gets "mixed up".

One solution might be to wrap all of the global data and allocate it "to the window" and then when a particular window is activated, a pointer would then be pointing at that block of data. However, I see this as a huge coding effort.

Another solution I was wondering about (and finally the question :-) is whether we could wrap the DLL and make it a .NET object that would be instantiated for each of the windows needing.

The question is can this be done in such a way so that each instance in completely independent of the other, thus removing the troubles we have with global variables?

Comment: If the multiple windows are on different threads, you could use thread-local data.

Comment: You probably can't make that work. Global variables in the DLL are allocated per-process. So unless you want to multiple copies of the same DLL (with different names), you can't get more than one copy of the global data.